# Is the use of "copia verae" correct?

Tags: declension

The sentence is:
*Copia verae virtutis multas culpas superare poterat.* It is from Wheelock's Latin by Frederic M. Wheelock, 6th edition, revised by Richard A. LaFleur. It is the number 5 sentence in Practice and Review part in chapter 8. Page number is 52.
In this sentence, is the use of "copia verae" correct? Why isn't it "copia vera"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously *copia verae* is not in agreement, so you have to look for something else *verae* agrees with. That something is *virtutis* (gen. sg. of *virtus, -utis, f.*). So you have:

> copia verae virtutis
> *the power of true virtue*

If it were *copia vera virtutis*, it would mean "the true power of virtue" (very nice example for how English does with word order what Latin does with endings, by the way), but that is evidently not what the author wanted to express.